# How can I find start and end index of a substring matched by regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex

For example, I have a string like this:

```
String string = "Some random string 1aaa5 some random string";
```

And I want to get start and end index of a substring "1aaa5" or similar, matched by a regex pattern:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d\\w+\\d");
```

In this case, result would be 20 and 24, for start and end respectively.

Is there a way to do this in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string)
if (matcher.find()) {
    start = matcher.start()
    end = matcher.end()
    text = matcher.group()
}
```

Comment: `if find` was the missing piece. Thanks!

Comment: Or `while` if there could be several matches.